# Updating database schema in Visual Studio 2012 database project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-schema, database-project

I created a new database project, imported schema from a database (which generated a bunch of sql). Now, how do I approach making schema changes? Say, I need to add a column, or change a column size - where do I put ALTER statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make the changes directly to the object. When you publish those changes, SSDT will figure out what needs to change and make the changes directly.

I've got a bunch of posts on SSDT that might be helpful and learned quite a bit from Jamie Thomson's post on DB Projects and SSDT over the years.

http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/10/all-ssdt-articles.html - will work, but takes a while to build the list sometimes.

http://schottsql.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary/-/SSDT - definitely works, but order is most recent to oldest.